# Python Django Template: Iterate through provided List

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am looking to loop in django template WITHOUT declaring variable.

```
{% for p in [ 'Value A', 'Value B' ] %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ p }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible ?
If not can I declare variable in template before loop ?

Answer (score 3):

its hacky and you shouldnt really do it ... templates are not designed for this (django-templates ... jinja templates are a different matter... switch to jinja backend is probably the "right" answer, second best answer is to pass the list in as a context variable... last choice is probably the following

```
{% with ["asd","World","dddd"] as my_var %}     
<html>
    {% for item in my_var %}
        <div> {{ item }} </div>
    {% endfor %}
</html>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Cool, however I have error "Could not parse the remainder..."

Comment: perhaps the official docs can help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the values in the views. It's much optimized, faster and recommended according to the documentation please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/performance/